# Подстрока до пробела

Tags: php

Есть строка вида

```
text text text @hello text text
```

Как мне вытащить именно `@hello` а именно все,что начинается с @ и до пробела
Пробовал через explode и strstr,не вышло что то. Получается найти  `@hello` и дальше до конца строки,а мне именно `@hello`  нужно

Comment: [регуляркой](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: немного быстрее два explode

Comment: ну тогда еще быстрее пройтись циклом по строке

Comment: `strstr(strstr($text, '@'), ' ', true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот. Легко и просто.

```
$text  = "text text text @hello text text ";
$a = strstr($text, '@');          // отсекаем всё слева
$pos = strpos($a, " ");           // узнаём сколько знаков до пробела справа
$final = substr($a, 0, $pos);     // отступим $pos количество символов, и удалим всё справа
echo $final;
```

---

Вот ещё проще:

```
$text  = "text text text @hello text text ";
$a = strstr($text, '@');      // обрезаем все слева до @
$b = strstr($a, ' ', true);   // если true, то обрезка будет справа, обрезаем после пробела
echo $b;
```

Укороченный вид: (автор @E_p)

```
$text  = "text text text @hello text text ";
$a = strstr(strstr($text, '@'), ' ', true);
echo $a;
```

Comment: он же выводит text,а надо hello

Comment: хм,странно ,я вот тут пробовал ,но все равно/выводит просто первый элемент http://phptester.net/

Comment: @zkolya Переделал по-другому... Видимо функция array_search() ищет целую строку, а не символ в строке.

Comment: Спасибо,круто,все работает

Comment: Если вы копируете чей то ответ в свой, то можно отметить чьё это авторство.

Comment: Вы строкой ошиблись. Я ожидал свой ник увидеть после **Вот ещё проще**.

Answer (score 2):

Например, регулярным выражением

```
$search = 'text text text @hello text text';

$patt = '~@[\S]+~';
preg_match_all($patt, $search, $all);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($all); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Решения выше считаю более лучшим вариантом, но и такой также имеет право на жизнь:

```
$text  = "text text text @hello text text ";

function findAfterDogText($text)
{
    $arr = explode(' ', $text);
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if ($value[0]=='@') {
            return substr($value, 1);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(findAfterDogText($text));
```